# Public key not found for RPM

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, gpg

I am trying to install  package on Redhat 5.5 using YUM but it always give me this error

```
[root@redhat64 Desktop]# yum install perl-Net-Server-0.97-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm   Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
Examining perl-Net-Server-0.97-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm: perl-Net-Server-0.97-1.el5.rf.noarch
Marking perl-Net-Server-0.97-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-Net-Server.noarch 0:0.97-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package
      Arch      Version          Repository                                Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 perl-Net-Server
      noarch    0.97-1.el5.rf    /perl-Net-Server-0.97-1.el5.rf.noarch    357 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)
Upgrade       0 Package(s)

Total size: 357 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 6b8d79e6


Public key for perl-Net-Server-0.97-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm is not installed
```

Note :: OS is 5.5 64bit running on virtual box and I have set GPGCHECK=0 in local YUM repository.

## Output of Repository

```
[root@redhat64 ~]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/* | grep -v "^#"
[rhel-debuginfo]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - Debug
baseurl=ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/$releasever/en/os/$basearch/Debuginfo/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release

[rhel-debuginfo-beta]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever Beta - $basearch - Debug
baseurl=ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/beta/$releasever/en/os/$basearch/Debuginfo/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-beta,file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
[rhel-local.repo]
name=Local Repo
Baseurl=file:///RPMS
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Im using the Local.repo as my main packages repository

Comment: What does `yum localinstall perl-Net-Server-0.97-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm` say?

Comment: checked what you said but its giving same error as mentioned in last two lines of Question

Comment: Could you add `cat /etc/yum.repos.d/*  | grep -v "^#"` to your Question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the Repoforge GPG key:

```
# rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
```

Comment: What this command will do??? But still I tried it and it gave me error **error: http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt: import read failed(-1).**

Comment: Re what it does: It "installs the Repoforge GPG key". That allows `yum` or `rpm` to accept packages signed with that key.

Comment: Re permission error: I just tried it, and it works here. You do have to do it as root, as indicated by the leading `#`.