# Public key for git-.....rpm is not installed

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, encryption, gpg

When attempting to install git (and probably other packages), I get this error:

```
$ sudo yum -y install git

Installing:
 git                       x86_64           1.7.11.3-1.el6.rfx           rmit-res-rhel6-local                             7.5 M
...
Downloading Packages:
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 6b8d79e6: NOKEY


Public key for git-1.7.11.3-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm is not installed
```

I see from other questions ([Public key not found for RPM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61239/public-key-not-found-for-rpm)) that the answer will probably be:

```
sudo rpm --import <SOMEKEY>
```

But what is the value of SOMEKEY here?

Also, what happened to my system to make this happen? What went wrong?

(This is a RHEL VM provisioned by a university ITS group. I have root access [obviously] but don't know its setup terribly well.)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, by a fun coincidence, the key referred to in the related question seemed to do the trick:

```
rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
```

But why?